# antlr4 two lexer rule match the same string

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

I'm currently using antlr4 to build a parser, but I encountered a problem which I tried my best but didn't figure out. Can you help me to explaain and solve it ?

```
# grammer file : PluginDoc.g4:

grammer PluginDoc

pluginDef : pluginName | pluginDesc;
pluginName : PluginName IDENTIFIER;
pluginDesc : PluginDesc TEXT;

PluginName '@pluginName'
PluginDesc '@pluginDesc'

IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z_]+;
TEXT : ~( ' ' | '\n' | '\t' )+;

input content is: 
@pluginName kafka
@pluginDesc abc
```

If I put IDENTIFIER before TEXT, I will get "mismatched input 'abc' expecting TEXT"
If I put TEXT before IDENTIFIER, I will get "mismatched input 'kafka' expecting IDENTIFIER"

Looks like both IDENTIFIER and TEXT are matched, how can I only match IDENTIFIER in pluginName and only match TEXT in pluginDesc ?

Comment: Just use `TEXT` for both, then validate the identifier name in a post-processing phase.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have several errors in the grammar that you posted:

The header of the file should specify *grammar*, not *grammer*. Your Lexer tokens PluginName and PluginDesc do not have a colon in front of them and semicolon to terminate them. It is also an (unwritten?) rule to write your parser rules as all lower-case and your lexer rules as all upper-case.

```
grammar PluginDoc;

pluginDef : pluginName | pluginDesc;
pluginName : PLUGIN_NAME IDENTIFIER;
pluginDesc : PLUGIN_DESC TEXT;

PLUGIN_NAME : '@pluginName';
PLUGIN_DESC : '@pluginDesc';

IDENTIFIER : [a-zA-Z_]+;
TEXT : ~( ' ' | '\n' | '\t' )+;
```

Some of the problems that I encountered while testing your grammar were due to the unhandled whitespace. First of all, you should include a Lexer rule to skip the whitespace at the end of the file after all of the other Lexer rules.

```
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;
```

Next, there is a problem with your `TEXT` and `IDENTIFIER` clashing with each other. When the character stream is tokenized by the Lexer, `kafka` and `abc` can be both `IDENTIFIER` and `TEXT` token. Since the Lexer lexes in a top-down fashion, they are both tokenized as whateve Lexer rule comes first in your grammar. This causes the error that you encounter - whatever you define as the second rule cannot be matched in the parser because it was not sent in as a token.

As suggested by Lucas, you should probably match both of these as `TEXT` and do the subsequent checking for validity of the input in your Listener/Visitor.

```
grammar PluginDoc;

pluginDef : (pluginName | pluginDesc)* EOF;
pluginName : PLUGIN_NAME TEXT;
pluginDesc : PLUGIN_DESC TEXT;

PLUGIN_NAME: '@pluginName';
PLUGIN_DESC: '@pluginDesc';

TEXT : ~[ \r\n\t]+;

WS: [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
```

I also changed the `pluginDef` Parser rule to

```
pluginDef : (pluginName | pluginDesc)* EOF;
```

since it was my impression that you want to input both `@pluginName X` and `@pluginDesc Y` at once and identify them. If this is not the case, feel free to change back to what you had before.

The resulting AST produced by the modified grammar above onyour sample input:
[image]

You can also run this with a text file as an input.

Comment: What does `EOF` mean?

Comment: @GaryGauh EOF is the built-in end of file identifier. This can be literal end of file if the input is a file, or the CTRL-Z/D in terminal depending on your OS. For your example here it would probably work without it just fine, but experience taught me to put it there to avoid problems later on.